# How can I deploy streamlit application in cpanel?

Tags: python, cpanel, web-deployment, streamlit

I tried to deploy the streamlit app in my cpanel, but I ran into issues.

How can I start the application? I tried shell command : `sudo streamlit run app.py` but could not get it running , is there a way out?

Comment: What happens when you run `sudo streamlit run app.py`? Is there an error message?